# Why is this template not rendering when I have cripsy forms installed?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm having trouble rendering a template for a signup.html page in django.

The error consists of:
**TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/create/
Error during template rendering
In template [PATH_NAME]\cryptoProj\backend\templates\signup.html, error at line 21
bootstrap4/uni_form.html**

Line 21 is:

```
<p>{{ form | crispy }}</p>
```

The full file is:

```
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block metadescription %}
    Sign up to get a new account with us. The perfect solution to buy and sell your Cryptocurrencies.
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
    Create a New Account - Crypto Dashboard
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div>
        {% if not form.is_valid %}
            <div class="mx-auto">
                <br>
                <h1 class="my_title text-center">Create a new account</h1>
                <br>
                <div class="col-9 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 mx-auto bg-light">
                    <br>
                    <p>Enter the following information to create a new account.</p>
                    <form method="post">
                        <p>{{ form | crispy }}</p>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Register Account</button>
                    </form>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="mx-auto">
                <br>
                <h1 class="my_title text-center">Your account has been successfully created</h1>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        Dear Customer,
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        Your account has been created and it is ready to use.
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <br>
{% endblock %}
```

I have crispy forms pip installed and added to installed_apps in settings so I'm stumped as to why this error is appearing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

replace line 21 with this one.

```
{% crispy form %}
```